# systemctl and journalctl can't find charon-system.service

Tags: linux, systemctl

If I run with grep, service is present in output

```
[root@maincore ~]# systemctl status --all | grep charon
       │   │ └─135060 grep --color=auto charon
         │ └─127087 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd
     Unit boot.automount could not be found.
     Unit boot.mount could not be found.
     Unit sysroot.mount could not be found.
       └─135060 grep --color=auto charon
Unit display-manager.service could not be found.
Unit ipa.service could not be found.
Unit krb5kdc.service could not be found.
Unit ntpd.service could not be found.
Unit ntpdate.service could not be found.
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
Unit sntp.service could not be found.
Main PID: 127087 (charon-systemd)
Status: "charon-systemd running, strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64, x86_64"
       └─127087 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd
 Jan 24 16:41:48 maincore charon-systemd[127087]: generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT  AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
 Jan 24 16:41:48 maincore charon-systemd[127087]: splitting IKE message (1856 bytes) into 2 fragments
 Jan 24 16:41:48 maincore charon-systemd[127087]: generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/2) ]
 Jan 24 16:41:48 maincore charon-systemd[127087]: generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/2) ]
 Jan 24 16:41:48 maincore charon-systemd[127087]: sending packet: (1236 bytes)

Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found.
Unit ypbind.service could not be found.
Unit yppasswdd.service could not be found.
Unit ypserv.service could not be found.
Unit ypxfrd.service could not be found.
       │ │ └─127087 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd
           │ └─135060 grep --color=auto charon
       │ └─127087 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd
       │ └─135060 grep --color=auto charon
         │ └─135060 grep --color=auto charon
Unit dirsrv.target could not be found.
Unit syslog.target could not be found.
```

But if I put unit name directly to systemctl or journalctl , it does not work

```
[root@maincore ~]# systemctl status charon-systemd
Unit charon-systemd.service could not be found.

[root@maincore ~]# journalctl -u charon-systemd
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-01-21 19:48:23 UTC, end at Mon 2021-01-25 00:29:45 UTC. --
-- No entries --
```

Logs are present from charon-systemd service.
Whats wrong?

```
[root@maincore ~]# systemctl list-units -t service 
UNIT                               LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                                       
auditd.service                     loaded active running Security       Auditing Service                                         
chronyd.service                    loaded active running NTP client/server                                                 
crond.service                      loaded active running Command Scheduler                                                 
dbus.service                       loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus                                          
dracut-shutdown.service            loaded active exited  Restore /run/initramfs on shutdown                                
getty@tty1.service                 loaded active running Getty on tty1                                                     
import-state.service               loaded active exited  Import network configuration from initramfs                       
irqbalance.service                 loaded active running irqbalance  daemon                                                 
kdump.service                      loaded active exited  Crash recovery kernel arming                                      
kmod-static-nodes.service          loaded active exited  Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel
loadmodules.service                loaded active exited  Load legacy module configuration                                  
mariadb.service                    loaded active running MariaDB 10.3 database server                                      
network.service                    loaded active exited  LSB: Bring up/down networking                                     
● nginx.service                      loaded failed failed  The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server                           
nis-domainname.service             loaded active exited  Read and set NIS domainname from /etc/sysconfig/network           
php-fpm.service                    loaded active running The PHP FastCGI Process Manager                                   
plymouth-quit-wait.service         loaded active exited  Hold until boot process finishes up                               
plymouth-quit.service              loaded active exited  Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen                                    
plymouth-read-write.service        loaded active exited  Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data                           
plymouth-start.service             loaded active exited  Show Plymouth Boot Screen                                         
polkit.service                     loaded active running Authorization Manager                                             
radiusd.service                    loaded active running FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server.                        
rngd-wake-threshold.service        loaded active exited  Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Wake threshold service              
rngd.service                       loaded active running Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon                              
rsyslog.service                    loaded active running System Logging Service                                            
sshd.service                       loaded active running OpenSSH server daemon                                             
sssd.service                       loaded active running System Security Services Daemon                                   
strongswan.service                 loaded active running strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using swanctl                 
systemd-fsck-root.service          loaded active exited  File System Check on Root Device                                  
systemd-journal-flush.service      loaded active exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storage                               
systemd-journald.service           loaded active running Journal Service                                                   
systemd-logind.service             loaded active running Login Service                                                     
systemd-random-seed.service        loaded active exited  Load/Save     Random Seed                                             
systemd-remount-fs.service         loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems                              
systemd-sysctl.service             loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables                                            
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev                                
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service     loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories                             
systemd-udev-trigger.service       loaded active exited  udev Coldplug all Devices                                         
systemd-udevd.service              loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager                                        
systemd-update-utmp.service        loaded active exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown                            
systemd-user-sessions.service      loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions                                              
tuned.service                      loaded active running Dynamic  System Tuning Daemon                                      
user-runtime-dir@1000.service      loaded active exited  /run/user/1000 mount wrapper                                      
user@1000.service                  loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000   

[root@maincore ~]# systemctl list-unit-files | grep charon 
[root@maincore ~]#
```

Comment: It's as if systemd had lost plenty of unit files, not only charon's. However, some charon processes are running and are therefore listed. I would have a look at the situation in `/etc/systemd/system` and `/lib/systemd/system` - do you find the unit files for the missing services? What do you get from `systemctl list-units -t service` or `systemctl list-unit-files`?

Comment: unit files not present in /etc/systemd/system and /lib/systemd/system.

Comment: I don't know what makes systemctl list services that aren't installed, such as `ntpd` (your system, which looks like RHEL or Centos, has `chronyd` as timeserver; it can't run both `ntpd` and `chronyd` at the same time). At some point, `ntpd` was installed, then removed(?) so that the unit file is now missing, though the service is listed. Charon as well - processes are still running, but the unit file is gone. Do you need Charon or do you want to get rid of it? In the latter case, kill the processes and `yum erase` it. In the former case, `yum reinstall` (assuming it's indeed RHEL or Centos).

Comment: Generally, something needs to be done about the long list of services that systemctl doesn't. Ensure the corresponding software packages are erased. Perhaps a `systemctl daemon-reload` is required. Or a reboot. Admittedly I don't have enough experience to explain your situation.

Comment: charon-systemd is part of Strongswan (see https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon-systemd), for which there is a service.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused the name of a process with the name of the systemd service that started it. There is not necessarily any relation between them.

To find the systemd service responsible for a running process, give its PID to `systemctl status`:

```
systemctl status <PID>
```

For example, you seem to be interested in the `charon-systemd` process with PID 127087, so you would run:

```
systemctl status 127087
```

Now you can see the actual service name and its status.

Comment: Thanx for your explanation!